# Tooltip Issue: Tooltip displays the not selected data

Tags: vega-lite

I've been working with Vega-Lite to make not stacked histogram having tooltips with [Legend Binding](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bind.html#legend-binding).

- Tooltip works well when all simbol legends are selected.

  - [Works well image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/conJw.png)
- However, I've encountered an issue that, when some simbol legends are selected, tooltip display upper unselected data.

  - [Issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQi0X.png)
- I expect that tooltip displays the data over mouse.

  - [Goal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D26O0.png)

You can view it here: [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-mWhIARlcU+3AGZtxuxG5924t85+TnpQsAMob8q3+93pTXw0gF-3jlrMJAA)
, and click `S1` in right `legend`, and move mouse on `x == 1` on right histogram

Any suggestions on how to rectify this or if there is an alternative workaround available would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the interaction is still picking up the underlying object despite the opacity. One option is to `"filter"` the data based on the interactive legend: `{"filter": "isDefined(legend_selector.legend) == false ? true : indexof(legend_selector.legend, datum.legend) >= 0"}`. Once you've applied this filter, a key part of ensuring it correctly is manually setting the legend scale so that the values that are filtered out still appear in the legend: `"scale": {"domain": ["S1", "S2"]}`. You can then simplify your `"opacity"` encoding to just set the value (without the conditional formatting). A working example is available in the online editor [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady3K5mGrIZsGEAOo0AJvTQAmAAzOlK2SbMWIACTgaWE6uAL4hSjhIAE5ICBBoANqgsrFwaCCC5HCytgD6EHCZUJhsUYogBUWYhpgAnjhp6DhsptVKJWRkmelwpJ6UxVGCANJwteXZKramZPGoCUaCpSAAuuEgTKa26Zlk2dtKOvpzC0d6uc6rIStKgki1cGXzyanpZxflyFEA1jX1jRtouUoMIcGhMFEGHB2mw2IITGDUBCoetbEhMChUC8EAC0RjcnZ+Jd1hCkLIIKpSghEqBVHdsNlEiAAB7lZmOcrjW5ZHJXBS0mjwx7pGgQAAicHUsjgtgAFLt9vlCnBiqVKAqcgBKAAEAF5ddrVEhBAVtQB+bXIuDa1DarZwZlsVTynl5SoqkpRdWuhTavEMBDevZa7UAPgNxJuIEmbGmsk0WJZhnUhW26FZ7To3XT5U28nQeel23W7OTukEaZZHMzmGzZkEgnW40TKYr6S5IDqDXSAEcGGSTBiTKRyhAMVBfqh6433HDli3y5WNQcKlBjY1QLY2MhTEyAMoARnKe45a3WbEiUDoze0xqhaGclAA7GIwtclHikAVMHNN+ikASthEoYrLzPwjgKG4EHgZBCiOFGpbzFBCgACywRBKFRs2CQHq4cF4QAzHhB5iG4RFuLhzhRsu+5Hkoh7HnRIAnse1bMaeb5AA).

Comment: FYI, Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Good catch @DavideBacci, must've been distracted when grabbing that one. Fixed now.

Comment: That's a clever solution - good work.

Comment: Thank you for your great suggestion!
I appreciate the detailed explanation and the modified example you provided in the Vega editor.
So, your suggestion made me understood using filter and scale.domain, encoding.opacity to solve issue.
I genuinely appreciate your assistance and the time you took to help me with this issue. @sabine